# SCP upload file problem

Tags: java, ssh

I need to upload file with SCP. I found on stackoverflow this library http://code.google.com/p/commons-net-ssh/
 I download .jar and add to BuildPath, but how to add username and password to this ?
I tried this but it doesn't work. If you have any other library that do this it will be fine . Any help ?

```
SSHClient ssh = new SSHClient();
//ssh.useCompression(); 
ssh.loadKnownHosts();
ssh.connect("localhost");
try {
    ssh.authPublickey(System.getProperty("user.name"));
    new SCPDownloadClient(ssh).copy("ten", "/tmp");
} finally {
    ssh.disconnect();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions:

1. You can create a key pair with `ssh-keygen` *without* a pass-phrase. Use `authPublickey(java.lang.String username, java.lang.String... locations)` to select the key for the connection.
2. You can save the password in a file which the Java code can read.

The security of the two solutions is about the same: It depends entirely on who can read the password/key file. Make it readable only by the user who runs the Java code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`authPassword`](https://github.com/shikhar/sshj/blob/master/src/main/java/net/schmizz/sshj/SSHClient.java#L211) method to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

```
SCPClient scp = conn.createSCPClient();
scp.put(localFileLoc,zipFileName,""/temp,"0777");
```

This helps me to use SCP. I have used `ganymed-ssh2-build251beta1.jar`.